# Jquery consume an umbraco webservice data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, umbraco

I have a webservice in umbraco, which doesnt seem to be parsed by my Jquery, when I run the code I do get the alert box coming up however it just has the message "undefined" repeated, where i would be expecting the header, please see the code below.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<NewsItem> GetNewsItems()
    {
        List<NewsItem> returnValue = new List<NewsItem>();

        foreach (umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node item in new umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node(190078).Children)
            returnValue.Add(new NewsItem() { Header = item.Name, path = item.Url, Id = item.Id });

        return returnValue;
    }
```

...

```
public class NewsItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

When I browse too it it is fine. the definition is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
<GetNewsItemsResponse xmlns="http://countryumbraco/">
  <GetNewsItemsResult>
    <NewsItem>
      <Header>string</Header>
      <path>string</path>
      <Id>int</Id>
    </NewsItem>
```

so far so good, my Jquery which consumes the webservice  is as follows :-

```
var webServiceURL = 'http://mydomain.com/umbraco/webservices/latestnews.asmx/GetNewsItems';

function CallService()
{
    $.ajax({

       type: "POST",
   url: webServiceURL, 
       dataType: "xml", 
   processData: false,
       success: OnSuccess, 
       error: OnError
    });

    return false;
}

function OnSuccess(xml)
{
   $(xml).find("NewsItem").each(function()
   {
    alert($(this).attr("Header"));
     });
}



function OnError(request, status, error)
{
    alert('Error');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
});
```

any ideas to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: did u try to parse data via $.parseXML

Comment: or try this one   $(xml).find('NewsItem').each(function(){
      var header= $(this).find('Header').text();alert(header);

Comment: sakir - that worked a treat thank you, add it as the answer

Comment: I am glad to it works fine for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(xml).find('NewsItem').each(function(){ 
var header= $(this).find('Header').text();alert(header); 

}
```